# Tween from material to material in ThreeJS

Tags: three.js, opacity, tween.js

Is there a way to tween materials on a mesh ?

i mean something like:
new TWEEN.Tween (mesh.mat1).to(mesh.mat2).start();

Ive tried somethings but with no succes

Thx for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With tween.js you can only tween numbers.

Comment: Thx, now its clear to me
BTW why my opacity tweening works no more (i use your three.js 69, it worked with r.49 fine) 
TWEEN.Tween(sphere.material).to({opacity: 0}, 500).start();

Comment: You need to set `material.transparent` to `true`.

Comment: Now it works as expected, even though I dont quite get why exactly was that necessary, but thx

Comment: Don't worry, you'll understand. Sooner or later.. ;)